# Convert JSON array of one to an object

Tags: javascript, json

Currently I have this:

```
{ 
"id": "1234"  
"elements": [
    {
      "fee": "blah",
      "fi": "blahblah",
      "fo": "blahblahblah",
      "fum": "blahblahblahblah"
    }
  ]
}
```

and I want to change it into this:

```
{ 
"id": "1234"  
"elements": {
    "fee": "blah",
    "fi": "blahblah",
    "fo": "blahblahblah",
    "fum": "blahblahblahblah"
  }
}
```

The JSON arrays I get only ever have one element in them so I am just trying to work out what is the best way with javascript to achieve the above?

Currently I do it this way but am curious if it's the best option.

```
for (var i = obj.elements.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  obj.element = obj.elements[i];
}
```

Comment: Why not just `obj.elements = obj.elements[0]`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code makes no sense. If there were ever two elements in the array, the second one would clobber the first.

If there really is only ever **one** item, you have no need at all for a loop. Just use

```
obj.element = obj.element[0];
```

Comment: Ahhhhh ok. Thanks for hastily putting me out of my misery. I now see the absurdity of my question and the lack of a need for the loop. Time I think for a bit of non screen time. See if my brain comes back.